# Access value of command argument search_url in __init__ within method

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am running a script like `scrapy runspider script.py -a search_url=www.website.com`

**UPDATED** class

```
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    base = 'http://www.website.com'
    def __init__(self, search_url):
        self.search_url = search_url
        self.start_urls = [self.base + search_url]

    def parse(self,response):
       print("self.search_url is {}".format(self.search_url))
```

Does this `print()` statement in `parse()` method look syntactically sound to print out the value of `self.start_urls()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `self.search_url` field in `BrickSetSpider` class object. Perhaps this field is set in base class' `__init__` method, but you don't call `__init__` of base class (you could do that inside `__init__` you defined. 
So the only field you have initialized is `self.start_urls`. You could print instead:

```
print("self.start_urls is {}".format(self.start_urls))
```

Or if you want to set `search_url` field you can also add following line to your `__init__`:

```
self.search_url = search_url
```

Comment: No, `search_url` is set in the command line `argument` how can i retrieve its value in `parse()` method

Comment: No it is not. You have to set it **explicitly** in your code. You probably initialize `search_url` argument of init, but it is does not mean you set `self.search_url` field of object of `BrickSetSpider` class. These are 2 different variables even if they have the same name.

Comment: Can you show me how to access it in `parse()` it gets hard coded in the command line `arg` but then is set as a param in `__init__` - thanks

Comment: You don't have to access it in `parse()`. You can set it inside `__init__` as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I've set the value of `site_url` in `__init__` like `self.search_url = search_url` how can I then access this `value` in `parse()`?

Comment: Can you see my updated code and question? Thank you.